# Como selecionar tabelas por prefixo [MYSQL]?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 20 conjuntos de tabelas diferentes dentro de um mesmo banco aonde cada uma delas corresponde a uma loja virtual. Visto que as minhas tabelas estão organizadas por prefixo, como posso selecionar todas as tabelas de um determinado prefixo para exportá-la?

Por exemplo se eu quiser exportar a tabela com prefixo ***z12_***?

O desempenho das minhas lojas pode ser afetado visto que tenho 20 tabelas dentro de um mesmo banco? O banco tem atualmente 250MB. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usa o phpMyAdmin, você pode fazer isso facilmente:

Selecione o banco de dados > Clique na aba exportar > Selecione a opção personalizado > Ache o prefixo que deseja exportar > Selecione a primeira tabela, depois pressione shift e selecione a última tabela > Clique em Executar (no fim da página).

Sobre o desempenho, vai depender do servidor que você usa. Fazer da forma como fez apenas fica um pouco mais desorganizado, pois o ideal seria criar um banco de dados para cada loja, mas não deixa mais lento por causa disso.